# What permission is required for a service account to deploy index.yaml to Google App Engine using gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have created a service account in order to deploy a project to google app engine.

The service account I have created has these two roles:

1. App Engine -> App Engine Admin
2. Storage -> Storage Object Admin

I downloaded the json key file, and then run these commands:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
gcloud -q app deploy app_deploy.yaml --version 1.0 --promote
gcloud -q app deploy --version 1.0 index.yaml queue.yaml
```

I got this error message:

```
You are about to update the following configurations:
 - zeetings-modular-konga/queue  (from [/Users/antkong/dev/app/queue.yaml])
 - zeetings-modular-konga/index  (from [/Users/antkong/dev/app/index.yaml])
Updating config [queue]...failed.    
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [403]:
  Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403.
  You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~myapp').
```

My question:

1) What permission do I need to get the last `gcloud -q app deploy` to work?

2) Where in google cloud sdk documentation I can find out the permissions?  My google-fu has failed me.